# phonegap Media object not definied error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, media

I am new in phoneGap currently I have issue to play audio by Media library

I have follow steps to enable Media plugin but it does not worked.

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-media
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-media-capture

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-extension
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file

phonegap platform add android

cordova platform update android@5.0

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture

And here is my code audio.js.

```
// Audio player
//
var my_media = null;

// Play audio
//
function playAudio(src,callbackFinishCallBack) {
    // Create Media object from src
    if (typeof Media !== 'undefined') {
        // the variable is defined
        alert("Error No Media Object defined..!");
        return;
    }
    var my_media = null;
    my_media = new Media(src,  // success callback
            function () {
                my_media.release();
                if(typeof callbackFinishCallBack == 'function')
                {
                    callbackFinishCallBack.call(this);
                }
            },
            // error callback
            function (err) {
                 alert('code: ' + err.code + '\n' +
                    'message: ' + err.message + '\n');
                my_media.release();
                if(typeof callbackError == 'function')
                {
                    callbackError.call(this);
                }  
            });

    // Play audio
    my_media.play();


}

/*function playAudio(src,callbackFinishCallBack) {
 // HTML5 Audio
    if (typeof Audio != "undefined") { 
        var audioRes = new Audio(src).play() ;
        alert("Called audio");
        audioRes.addEventListener('onended', function(){
            alert();
            callbackFinishCallBack.call(this);
        });

    // Phonegap media
    } else if (typeof device != "undefined") {
        alert("Called Media");

        if (typeof Media !== 'undefined') {
            // the variable is defined
            alert("Error No Media Object Defnied");
            return;
        }

        // Android needs the search path explicitly specified
        if (device.platform == 'Android') {
            src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
        }

        var mediaRes = new Media(src,
            function onSuccess() {
                my_media.release();
                if(typeof callbackFinishCallBack == 'function')
                {
                    callbackFinishCallBack.call(this);
                }
            },
            function onError(e){
                console.log("error playing sound: " + JSON.stringify(e));
            });
        mediaRes.play();

    } else {
        console.log("no sound API to play: " + src);
        alert(src);
    }
 }*/
```

Simply I used in on device ready code over here ..
index.html

```
 function onDeviceReady() 
    {
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://erronak.com/dev/child_app/index.php",
           dataType:'json'
        }).done(function( row ) {

          $("#main_image").attr("src",row.image);
          $("#popup_name").html(row.name);
          $("#audio_hidden").val(row.audio);


          //Start replacing operation..
          //stopAudio();
          //alert(row.audio);
          playAudio( row.audio,function(){
            //Let Display text over here..
            $( "#popup_name" ).popup( "open" );

          });
```

Here is my main configuration file config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-admob" spec="~4.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-libgoogleadmobads" spec="C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\google-iosadmobads-master" />

</widget>
```

Here is my android/res/xml/config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="connectivity">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.appfeel.cordova.connectivity.Connectivity" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="AdMobAds">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.appfeel.cordova.admob.AdMobAds" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture" />
    </feature>
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
</widget>
```

androidMenifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.cordova.hellocordova" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
</manifest>
```

When run above code it give me 
Error No Media Object defined..!

I have tried so many I am very near to solution, please help me to come out..

Comment: I have tried so much possibilities but I feel I am almost near at solution..

Answer (score 1):

Replace playAudio function with below code.

function playAudio(src,callbackFinishCallBack) {

```
var my_media = null;
my_media = new Media(src,  // success callback
        function () {
            my_media.release();
            if(typeof callbackFinishCallBack == 'function')
            {
                callbackFinishCallBack.call(this);
            }
        },
        // error callback
        function (err) {
             alert('code: ' + err.code + '\n' +
                'message: ' + err.message + '\n');
            my_media.release();
            if(typeof callbackError == 'function')
            {
                callbackError.call(this);
            }  
        });

// Create Media object from src
if (typeof my_media !== 'undefined') {
    // the variable is defined
    alert("Error No Media Object defined..!");
    return;
}

// Play audio
my_media.play();
```

}

Comment: No dude, it still same go into  // the variable is defined and alert("Error No Media Object defined .. !